# Text underneath the footer does not go away Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, inspect

I have been trying to remove some texts that read "Home About us Contact" right below my footer. I've checked the widgets and nothing is showing up from there that relates to this. I've been trying to use Additional CSS on WordPress to hide it and using Inspector to figure out the div, and it reads #Text in between several script codes. does anyone know how to get rid of this or at least hide it?]

This is the code of that problem using inspect

```
<script>...<script> <div id="page" class="site">_</div> <!--#page--> "Home About Us Contact Us" ==$0 <script>...Script>
```

The website is showandheal.org The site and underneath the footer is "Home About Us Contact Us" I can't remove

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1kWM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Inspect and find its id or class and hide it using css(display:none;) Or Go to your footer.php page from your theme editor and hide it from there.